# Cant access my wordpress.org locally

Tags: urls

Hi I have created a wordpress.org website with phpmyadmin where it is located locally on my computer.[image] I went to transfer my domain purchased through namecheap.com and I put my recently purchased domain address in both url address spots in the settings now I cant access my files to change it back.[image] I have attached screen shots of what I'm getting.[image]

Comment: To access and change back, reference the options table in the database. Check your local configuration to ensure everything is correct before changing to new domain ie adjust your hosts file so the dns points to local ip.

Answer (score 0):

As you configure the domain name in local WordPress setup, it will not be able to resolve the content from DNS/Domain.

You have 2 ways,

1. Change the setting from backend. i.e. config file and DB.

OR

2. As a simple hack, you can create a host entries on your local system to your local web server.
   Simply, add a single line like below to your hosts file,

127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com

Assuming, your local server is in your local PC only.
You can use google to find how you can change your hosts file if you are not aware of the same.
Please, backup the hosts file before any performing any changes.